# How to invoke method with CVaListPointer parameters in Swift

Tags: swift, logging, swift2, nslog

How should I invoke the following method? The method belongs to a class that prints logs.

```
func log(format: String!, withParameters valist: CVaListPointer)
```

What I want to achieve, would look like this in Objective-C:

```
NSLog(@"Message %@ - %@", param1, param2);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`CVaListPointer` is the Swift equivalent of the C `va_list` type
and can be created from an `[CVarArgType]` array using `withVaList()`.

Example:

```
func log(format: String!, withParameters valist: CVaListPointer) {
    NSLogv(format, valist)
}

let args: [CVarArgType] = [ "foo", 12, 34.56 ] 
withVaList(args) { log("%@ %ld %f", withParameters: $0) }
```

Output:

```
2016-04-27 21:02:54.364 prog[6125:2476685] foo 12 34.560000
```

For **Swift 3,** replace `CVarArgType` by `CVarArg`.

Comment: What can you recommend for a function that takes `CVarArg` instead of `CVaListPointer`?

Comment: If replace `CVarArgType` by `CVarArg`, compiler will show an error because of type, and if you try to cast `CVarArg` to `CVarArgType`, you will get a crash.

Comment: There is `getVaList()` method also which return `CVaListPointer` given a list of `CVarArg`.

Comment: @AhmedOsama: According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1539624-getvalist, `withVaList` is the preferred method.